# Vertical UISlider constraints

Tags: swift, uislider

I am creating a vertical UISlider. I have created the view it is in using all code. (the rest of the storyboard elements are constrained using interface builder)

From what I have read, to create a vertical UISlider you give the UISlider a width and then rotate it. Since the height of the container that the UISlider sits in varies by screen size I do not want to give it a fixed height (width).

This is what I was thinking

```
    // Mark: Slider View

    let leftSlider = UISlider()
    let centerSlider = UISlider()
    let rightSlider = UISlider()

    let colorSliders = [leftSlider, centerSlider, rightSlider]

    for slider in colorSliders {

        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sliderContainer.addSubview(slider)

        let w = sliderContainer.bounds.width
        slider.bounds.size.width = w
        slider.center = CGPoint(x: w/2, y: w/2)
        slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

        slider.value = 0
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = 255

        let sliderTopConstraint = slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHiddenView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5)
        let sliderBottomConstraint = slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 5)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([sliderTopConstraint, sliderBottomConstraint])
        slider.backgroundColor = .purple
        slider.isEnabled = true
        slider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    let sliderContainerWidth: CGFloat = sliderContainer.frame.width


    let centerSliderHorizontalConstraints = centerSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.centerXAnchor)

    let widthConstraint = centerSlider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sliderContainerWidth)

    let centerSliderWidthConstraint = centerSlider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerSliderHorizontalConstraints, centerSliderWidthConstraint, widthConstraint])
```

But when I run it I get this

[image]

which is far better than what I had earlier today. However, I would like the slider to be normal width..and well look normal just vertical

Any ideas on what I missed?
(Oh ignore that little purple offshoot to the left, that is the other 2 sliders that I added but didn't constrain yet.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're changing the `bounds` and the `transform` of your `UISlider` and are using Auto-Layout at the same time so it can be a little confusing.

I suggest you don't modify the `bounds` but use Auto-Layout instead. You should set the slider width to its superview height, and center the slider inside its superview. This way, when you rotate it, its height (after rotation) which is actually its width (before rotation) will be equal to its superview height. Centering the slider vertically will make sure the slider is touching the bottom and the top of its superview.

```
slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.heightAnchor
slider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.centerYAnchor)

slider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.centerXAnchor)
```

If you want to place one of the 2 remaining sliders to the left or right of their superview, don't center it horizontally but do the following instead:

```
slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.leadingAnchor)

slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sliderContainer.trailingAnchor)
```

Also, carefully check your console for Auto-Layout error logs.

**EDIT:**
I checked the above code on a test project, here's my view controller code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var containerView: UIView!


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let leftSlider = UISlider()
        let centerSlider = UISlider()
        let rightSlider = UISlider()
        let colorSliders = [leftSlider, centerSlider, rightSlider]

        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        for slider in colorSliders {
            slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            containerView.addSubview(slider)

            slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

            constraints.append(slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor))
            constraints.append(slider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor))

            slider.backgroundColor = .purple
        }
        constraints.append(leftSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor))
        constraints.append(centerSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor))
        constraints.append(rightSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

And here's what I got:
[image: Test Project Result]

Comment: ill go through my error logs, but the above suggested code did not improve things at all

Comment: I added some sample code I ran inside an empty project, please check my answer again!
I think you were adding too many constraints because I didn't have to use your last lines of code which was adding additional constraints.

Answer (score 1):

*(as of July 7, 2017)*

```
self.customSlider = [[UISlider alloc] init]];
self.customView = [[UIView alloc] init];

//create the custom auto layout constraints that you wish the UIView to have

[self.view addSubview:self.customView];
[self.customView addSubview:self.customSlider];
self.slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);

/*Create the custom auto layout constraints for self.customSlider to have these 4 constraints:
    //1. self.customSlider CenterX = CenterX of self.customView
    //2. self.customSlider CenterY = CenterY of self.customView
    //3. self.customSlider width = self.customView height
    //4. self.customSlider height = self.customView width
*/
```